# Laravel Hash::check() always return false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have profile form for user can edit own profiles. in this form I have current password. that must be match from seved into database.

Form:

```
{{ Form::password('currPassword', array('id'=>'currPassword')) }}
```

i want to have this function in Controller to check this with database.

```
$data = User::find($id);
if( ! Hash::check( $data->password , Input::get('currPassword') ) )
{
    return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
        ->with('message', 'Current Password Error !')
        ->withInput();
}
```

hashed `123456` password into database is ok and after putting `123456` in `currPassword` that must be return `TRUE` but that return `FALSE` always.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197989/laravel-5-using-bcrypt-on-same-string-gives-different-values/39198006#39198006) for more details.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're using the wrong argument order. It's `Hash::check($input, $hash)`, not the other way around.

Short tinker example:

```
[1] > $pw = 123456;
// 123456
[2] > $hashed = Hash::make($pw);
// '$2y$10$xSugoyKv765TY8DsERJ2/.mPIOwLNdM5Iw1n3x1XNVymBlHNG4cX6'
[3] > Hash::check($hashed, $pw);
// false
[4] > Hash::check($pw, $hashed);
// true
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and solved it like this:

I found that I was using the Hash::make function in my RegistrationService class and more important that I had **already** used the **setPasswordAttribute** function in my **User model** which were quickly forgotten:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
   ...

    /**
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
}
```

So the password was double hashed and of course every Hash::check call was incorrect and return false.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a Seeder which generated Super Admin, which called hash, and afterwards while working on User Management module, I did the same thing as you

Comment: Thank you. I was making the same mistake.

Answer (score 7):

> Hash::check() has two parameters first one is plane password and
>   another is hashed password. If password matched with hash it will
>   return true.

```
Hash::check(normal_password,hashed_password);
```

**Example :**

```
Hash::check('123456a','$2y$10$.XB30GO4jn7bx7EauLrWkugIaCNGxiQCgrFTeFDeSSrGdQYd6Rneq');
```

Answer (score 3):

Though above answers are valid for the question provided, I'm adding more explanation to give details insights

**Verifying A Password Against A Hash**

The check method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash. However, if you are using the LoginController included with Laravel, you will probably not need to use this directly, as this controller automatically calls this method:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

**check() method is declare in HasherInterface**

This method is to Check the given plain value against a hash.

```
 bool check(string $value, string $hashedValue, array $options = array())
```

Check the given plain value against a hash.

**Parameters**

string  $value
string  $hashedValue
array   $options

**Return Value**

bool

**For your example :**

```
$data = User::find($id);
if( ! Hash::check(Input::get('currPassword') , $data->password  ) )
{
    return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
        ->with('message', 'Current Password Error !')
        ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after spending 2 hours to work it out, I found that I was hashing the password twice before updating it.
1. From the PasswordResetController,
2. And in User model, I had this function:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{   
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

Comment: Saved me day! Had same problem, two devs on same project, one set password in controller, the other setting password in observer..

Comment: hi sohal i also have like this, so how to match now ???

Comment: @MAmirShahzad: ```Hash::check( $request->password, $user->password) )``` you need to make sure you are not hashing `$request->password` before `Hash::check()`.

Comment: ok it works

Thank you