# comparing hash password laravel 4

Tags: php, json, hash, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a custom login function in Laravel 4 but I don't know how to compare password with hash password that has been stored.

This is my controller

```
public function login($email,$password)
{
    $user=UserMobile::where('email','=',$email)->count();
    if($user==0)
    {
        return Response::json("Invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        $user=UserMobile::where('email','=',$email)->first();
        if(Hash::check($password,$user->password)) 
        {
            return Response::json($user);
        }
        else
        {
            return Response::json("Error");
        }
    }       

}
```

When I try to check it in postman, it keeps returning the return Response::json("Error");. Can somebody help please? thanks in advance

Comment: argument one supposed to be real password and argument two should be user entered password. Hash::check($password,$pengguna->password), is it correct?

Comment: You must check the input password with the user password `Hash::check($password,$user->password) `

Comment: @techLove $user->password is hash password while $password is input password

Comment: @SekarAnindya exactly. switch them.

Comment: @techLove still return to error

Comment: when you dump $user just before if(Hash)... line, does it return the right result?

Comment: @techLove yup, it return the right result

Comment: try on separate page may be. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495502/laravel-hashcheck-allways-return-false

Comment: @techLove it keep returning to error