# Laravel Update password validation

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

i have got an Edit Form where user will enter his new Password , i want to check if password entered matches the password already exist in the database if it matches then its an error "New Password cannot be same as old password"

this is the code i tried and its not working for me !! :(

```
if(\Hash::check($request->password,$old_password)){
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['message', 'New Password cannot be same as old password']);
}
```

Comment: You can follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495502/laravel-hashcheck-allways-return-false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Hash::check() allways return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495502/laravel-hashcheck-allways-return-false)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i tried that solution and it did not work for me :(

Comment: @user3315353 Please check my answer  hope this work for you

Comment: Have you checked you are definitely getting the values you expected in `$request->password` and `$old_password`? Otherwise your code looks correct on first glance when comparing it against the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing). In terms of not working, how is it not working? Is it not re-directing, is it throwing an error? Is it doing nothing? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Hash::check("ValueForEnteredpassword", "HashOldPassword")) { 
      //your code  
    }   else { 
    //Your error message 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this example :

```
if(!Hash::check($input['current_password'], $user->password)){

   dd('Return error with current passowrd is not match.');

}else{

   dd('Write here your update password code');

}
```

Hope this example for you !!!