# laravel 7 sanctum Hash::check always returns false

Tags: php, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to build laravel auth api with sanctum and I followed the doc but getting this error:

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "data": [
        "The provided credentials are incorrect."
    ]
}
```

}

Here's the controller:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'data' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
        ];

        return response($response, 201);

    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

}
```

I found this solution but it returns "true" even if the password is wrong:

> [Laravel Hash::check() always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495502/laravel-hashcheck-always-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way, using `attempt`

```
$request->validate([
  'email' => 'required|email|string',
  'password' => 'required|string',
  'device_name' => 'required',
]);
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
return response()->json([
  'message' => 'Unauthorized'
], 401);
$user = $request->user();
$token = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
//return....
```